# managing the location of executable files in MinGW

Tags: mingw

actually i'm using MinGW with GCC and the executable output files are generated always on the desktop ; is there any option to customize the location of the executable output file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the executeable output file with the -o flag.

For example:

```
gcc myFile.c -o "C:\path\to\output\myProgram.exe"
```